# Angular-cli.json after ejecting the project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, webpack, angular-cli

My question is simple, is `.angular-cli.json` still usefull when using webpack and after having the project ejected ?

I see that `"ejected": true` has been added to the file. So does this flag means that every configuration in this file is not used anymore ?

Comment: so did you remove `angluar-cli.json` after all?

Answer (score 0):

Probably not if you're not planning to revert ejecting the webpack config. Since after ejection you can't use `ng build` command anymore and have to use `npm run build` which simply runs `webpack`:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack",
```

and nowhere inside the `webpack.config.js` the `angular-cli.json` is used. You can test it for yourself. Simply delete the file and you'll see that you will still get a functional build.

Answer (score 0):

Some sections of `.angular-cli.json` like `scripts`, `styles`, `environmets` is used to pass params in to webpack when you `ng serve/build` etc.

After you `ng eject` you loosing all `ng` webpack related commands like 
`ng build`, `ng test`, `ng serve`, `ng e2e`. after that you had to use `npm run` instead, you check your `package.json` `scripts` section fro that matter.

But, even after you `ng eject` you still need the `.angular-cli.json` if you want to use Angular CLI scaffolding [ng generate(ng g)](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/docs/documentation/generate), etc as if you remove `.angular-cli.json` and want to run say `ng g service auth` you will get an error `Unable to find any apps in '.angular-cli.json'.`

You might wanna check these issues for more details on `ng eject`:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6302
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2895